# BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm scraping a news article using BeautifulSoup trying to only return the text body of the article itself, not all the additional "noise". Is there any easy way to do this?

```
import bs4
import requests

url = 'https://www.cnn.com/2018/01/22/us/puerto-rico-privatizing-state-power-authority/index.html'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
element = soup.select_one('div.pg-rail-tall__body #body-text').text
print(element)
```

Trying to exclude some of the information returned such as

> {CNN.VideoPlayer.handleUnmutePlayer = function
>   handleUnmutePlayer(containerId, dataObj) {'use strict';var
>   playerInstance,playerPropertyObj,rememberTime,unmuteCTA,unmuteIdSelector
>   = 'unmute_' +

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import bs4
import requests

url = 'https://www.cnn.com/2018/01/22/us/puerto-rico-privatizing-state-power-au$'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
elementd = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'zn-body__paragraph'})
elementp = soup.findAll('p', {'class': 'zn-body__paragraph'})
for i in elementp:
    print(i.text)
for i in elementd:
    print(i.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The *noise*, as you call it, is the text in the `<script>...</script>` tags (JavaScript code). You can remove it using `.extract()` like:

```
for s in soup.find_all('script'):
    s.extract()
```

You can use this:

```
r = requests.get('https://edition.cnn.com/2018/01/22/us/puerto-rico-privatizing-state-power-authority/index.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

[x.extract() for x in soup.find_all('script')]  # Does the same thing as the 'for-loop' above
element = soup.find('div', class_='pg-rail-tall__body')
print(element.text)
```

Partial Output:

> (CNN)Puerto Rico Gov. Ricardo Rosselló announced Monday that the
>   commonwealth will begin privatizing the Puerto Rico Electric Power
>   Authority, or PREPA. In comments published on Twitter, the governor
>   said the assets sale would transform the island's power generation
>   system into a "modern" and "efficient" one that would be less
>   expensive for citizens.He said the system operates "deficiently" and
>   that the improved infrastructure would respond more "agilely" to
>   natural disasters. The privatization process will begin "in the next
>   few days" and occur in three phases over the next 18 months, the
>   governor said.JUST WATCHEDSchool cheers as power returns after 112
>   daysReplayMore Videos ...MUST WATCHSchool cheers as power returns
>   after 112 days 00:48San Juan Mayor Carmen Yulin Cruz, known for her
>   criticisms of the Trump administration's response to Puerto Rico after
>   Hurricane Maria, spoke out against the move.Cruz, writing on her
>   official Twitter account, said PREPA's privatization would put the
>   commonwealth's economic development into "private hands" and that the
>   power authority will begin to "serve other interests.